# Usage of malloc with many structs in c

Tags: c, struct, malloc

I try to store many things with my struct. The variables seem to be stored within the "do-while", but when I try to access an element stored after the do-while, the element is gone.
What did I do wrong?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct Sauto {
int part;

};

int main() {
int i=0;
struct Sauto *car;

do {
    car = malloc(sizeof(struct Sauto)+(sizeof(struct Sauto)*i));
    struct Sauto car[i];

    printf("part%i:", i);
    scanf("%i", &car[i].part);
    printf("part%i is %i\n", i, car[i].part);
    i++;
} while (i<3);
printf("part 0 is %i\n", car[0].part);
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 7):

You redeclared a variable with the same name "car". Delete the declaration in the do-while loop.

Comment: You want me to fix your program ?
Sorry, you have to do it yourself, but I can give you hint.
You declared line 10 a variable nammed "car" which type is "struct Sauto *", and line 14, you declared a variable nammed "car" which type is "struct Sauto []". So when you want to manipule "car", which variable will be modified ? That's why you should delete the second "car (or rename it).
By the way, "i" = 0 at the begining, so your first malloc will be a malloc(0), and I don't think this is what you want. Same for the second "car", it will be "car[0]" ...

Comment: @Tom: The initial malloc is not zero length because he allocates `sizeof(struct Sauto) + (sizeof(struct Sauto)*i)` so it is always at least `sizeof(struct Sauto)`, but it is academic since it is still incorrect to reassign `car` and leak the previous allocation.

Comment: @Clifford : You're rigth. I'm not really used to the kind of malloc that I didn't even think there is a sizeof(struct Sauto) + ...

Comment: @Tom's : Yes the code is somewhat unconventional, not following expected idioms -  `sizeof(struct Sauto) * (i + 1)` would have made more sense perhaps.

Answer (score 0):

You have two errors:

1. In each iteration of the loop you allocate a new buffer of increasing length and reassign `car` repeatedly.
2. You instantiate an array `car` in the loop that shadows the dynamically allocated `car`, and worse you re-isntantiate it on each iteration

Neither the reallocation and assignment nor the reinstantiation are valid; in the first case you have a memory leak, and in both cases only the last element of the currently allocated or in-scope data is assigned.  In the case of the re-instantiation, that might appear to work *within* the loop by dumb luck simply by reusing the same memory on each iteration, but outside the loop the array is out of scope and the unused last allocation of `car` is used, which will never have bees assigned anything.

To fix these either:

```
struct Sauto* car = malloc( sizeof(struct Sauto) * NUMBER_OF_CARS );

do 
{
    ...
    i++;
} while ( i < NUMBER_OF_CARS );
```

or

```
struct Sauto car[NUMBER_OF_CARS];

do 
{
    ...
    i++;
} while ( i < NUMBER_OF_CARS );
```

Essentially only one instantiation/allocation of `car` outside the loop.

If you do not know *a priori* how many iterations will be performed, it is possible to use realloc() within the loop to expand the allocation.  However this can be very inefficient since it requires reallocation and copying of the data on each iteration.

```
struct Sauto* car = NULL ;

do 
{
    car = realloc( car, sizeof(struct Sauto) * (i + 1) ) ;

    '''

} while( !finished );
```

Comment: You forgot to put "car" at the beginning of the realloc, and it's better to retrieve the result of realloc in an another variable.

Comment: @Tom - Thanks, fixed the error.  With respect to the result of realloc(), I kind of agree, but would suggest that using realloc in the first instance is a bad idea - especially in the naive manner suggested here.  Moreover the original code lacks any error checking of the allocation or user input, and the question is not about that, so for the sake of keeping on-topic and brief I have omitted that - Valakor should however take note - it is good advice.